# Can shinydashboard use Tabpanels and have a nav bar?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am currently using shinydashboard but I would like to have different sidbar menues associated with content in the main body. Is this possible with shinydashboard?

For example:

I would like to have something like this
https://gallery.shinyapps.io/CDCPlot/

See how when you click on the nav bar options the sidebar menu changes as well as the body.

Is that possible in shinydashboad?  I like the look and feel of shinydashboard and would rather not go back to shiny.

THe underlying code is here:  https://github.com/NLMichaud/WeeklyCDCPlot/blob/master/ui.R

and uses tabpanels and  navbar. Is there something similar in shinydashboard?

Any examples with code?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is tricky and might not be possible because in shinydashboard, top-level navigation controls are located inside the dashboardSidebar (on the left side) and the content is contained inside dashboardBody (on the right side). If you place a navMenu inside dashboardBody, it would have to belong to a specific sidebar item and would disappear if you later click on another sidebar item.

You might need to change the way you want to achieve this. Depending on what you want to do, you might try :

creating a dashboardSidebar with menu items that would normally into the top-menu, and you can place all the controls for that menu under the associated tabItem. You can even make it all dynamic by using `renderMenu()` in server.R :

```
output$menu <- renderMenu({
   sidebarMenu(id = "sidebMenu",
       menuItem("Load Data", tabName = "loadData", icon = icon("database"),
          actionButton("press", "Press me")
   )
})
```

The disadvantage of this is probably that the number of controls you can put inside a sidebar menu is limited while it still looks good. But this is how dashboard is made.

or

using a fullscreen dashboard without sidebar with `dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)` and use a navigation menu in a similar way as in the example you mentioned. You will have no shinydashboard's sidebar and you would have to make your own sidebar just like in your example. This way, you might still enjoy the other features offered by shinydashboard like notifications, boxes, skins, status boxes etc. But this is just a suggestion, it is up to you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of shiny dashboards is that, by default, it doesn't allow for navigation bars on the header, which is what I am assuming is what you are asking. It is basically, because the Bootstrap framework that uses HTML, CSS and JS for responsive designs didn't include that option. Hence, if you search on internet there are multiple ways to do it. But all of them have one thing in common: The logic. You need to modify the HTML to include the option you are looking for:

1. Create an HTML object that is a navbar panel in the header of your document.
2. Create elements (the nav panels) into the HTML object and give them ids.
3. Create buttons that correspond to the ids of the nav Panels.

In order to be able to navigate on through the different panels, the logic is a bit different to a standard shiny dashboard.

1. Create a reactive expression on your HTML that registers clicks on the buttons and that assigns the values you want (for instance, something like clickedTab()). Most logical is to assign the values of the nav panels you assigned previously.
2. Call in your shiny server this reactive element.
3. Use uiOutput() to run the parts of the server code that you want depending on the tab you are in. For that you will need to create a reactive object (i.e. ObserveEvent()) that registers when you click the tabs, and then run parts of code inside if{} statements, where the condition will be that the clickedTAb() == "tabid".

Answer (score -1):

maybe you want something like:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  navbarPage(title = "AA Tester", 
             windowTitle ="AA Tester", 
             id="tabactive", 
             tabPanel("Explore Funds", icon = icon("table"),
                      tags$body(
                        class="skin-blue sidebar-mini control-sidebar-open",
                        dashboardPagePlus(
                          sidebar_fullCollapse=TRUE,
                          dashboardHeaderPlus(
                            disable = T,
                            enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
                            rightSidebarIcon = "gears"),
                          dashboardSidebar(),
                          dashboardBody(),
                          rightsidebar = rightSidebar(
                            background = "dark",
                            rightSidebarTabContent(
                              id = 1,
                              title = "Controllers",
                              icon = "desktop",
                              active = TRUE
                            ))
                        ))
                      ),
             tabPanel("Holdings Analysis",icon = icon("line-chart"))
             )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Really hard to see your code here. Could format it and make it much narrower!

Comment: I am afraid this does not work. First, this is based on an older version of shinydashboardPlus. And once I fixed that, the layout is completely broken. It does not seem that this is a reliable way.