# Make inputs in a sidebar persistent through tabs

Tags: css, r, shiny

I would like to have both a persistent sidebar (as in `shinydashboard` layout) and a navigation bar with tabs (as in `shiny::navbarPage` layout). I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145608/how-to-combine-top-navigation-navbarpage-and-a-sidebar-menu-sidebarmenu-in-s/62663257#62663257) that seems to correspond to what I want.

The problem is that inputs in the sidebar are not persistent through tabs, i.e when switching tabs, the inputs in the sidebar are not displayed anymore (at the contrary of `shinydashboard` sidebar for example). Here's an example I cannot really minimize more since a lot of it is CSS:

```
library(shiny)
library(bootstraplib)

# boot dash layout funs ---------------------------------------------------


boot_side_layout <- function(...) {
  div(class = "d-flex wrapper", ...)
}

boot_sidebar <- function(...) {
  div(
    class = "bg-light border-right sidebar-wrapper",
    div(class = "list-group list-group-flush", ...)
  )
}

boot_main <- function(...) {
  div(
    class = "page-content-wrapper",
    div(class = "container-fluid", ...)
  )
}

# css ---------------------------------------------------------------------

css_def <- "
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container-fluid, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}


.sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

.page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper, .page-content-wrapper {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  font-size: 1.1rem
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-wrapper {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;

  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
    position: fixed;
  }

  .page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}

"


# app ---------------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- tagList(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css_def))),
  bootstrap(),
  navbarPage(
    collapsible = TRUE,
    title = "",
    tabPanel(
      "Statistics",
      boot_side_layout(
        boot_sidebar(
          selectInput(
            "variables",
            "Variables",
            NULL
          )
        ),
        boot_main(
          fluidRow(
            dataTableOutput("statistics")
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    
    tabPanel(
      "Plots",
      boot_side_layout(
        boot_sidebar(
          
        ),
        boot_main(
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$statistics <- renderDataTable(mtcars[10, 10])
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I make these inputs persistent through sidebar? (If somebody knows of another *simple* way to mix persistent sidebar with navbar, please show it as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using a `sidebarLayout` with a `navbarPage` in `mainPanel`?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", "Select", c("a", "b", "c"))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      navbarPage(
        "App Title",
        tabPanel("Plot"),
        tabPanel("Summary"),
        tabPanel("Table")
      )    
    )
    
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT

Or something like this?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  div(
    style = "display: flex; flex-direction: column;",
    div( #~~ Main panel ~~#
      navbarPage(
        "Old Faithful Geyser Data",
        tabPanel(
          "Plot",
          plotOutput("ggplot")
        ),
        tabPanel("Summary"),
        tabPanel("Table")
      )    
    ),
    wellPanel( #~~ Sidebar ~~#
      style = "width: 300px;",
      sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

## EDIT

Like this to have the sidebar on the left:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(ggplot2)

CSS <- "
.sidebar {
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 300px;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(CSS))),
  
  div( #~~ Main panel ~~#
    navbarPage(
      "Old Faithful Geyser Data",
      tabPanel(
        "Plot",
        div(
          style = "display: flex;",
          div(class = "sidebar"),
          plotOutput("ggplot")
        )
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Summary",
        div(
          style = "display: flex;",
          div(class = "sidebar"),
          verbatimTextOutput("summary")
        )
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Table",
        div(
          style = "display: flex;",
          div(class = "sidebar"),
          tableOutput("table")
        )
      ),
      id = "navbar"
    )    
  ),
  wellPanel( #~~ Sidebar ~~#
    id = "sidebar", 
    sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
  output[["summary"]] <- renderPrint({
    list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
  })
  output[["table"]] <- renderTable({
    iris[1:10,]
  })
  observeEvent(input[["navbar"]], {
    selector <- 
      sprintf("$('div.tab-pane[data-value=\"%s\"] div.sidebar')", input[["navbar"]])
    runjs(paste0(selector, ".append($('#sidebar'));"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

## EDIT

Here is an improvement of the above way. I've made some convenient functions `tabPanel2` and `sidebar` to help the user. And I use `fluidRow` and `column` instead of using a `display: flex;`. This allows to have a sidebar width relative to the screen size. The example below also shows how to not include the sidebar in a tab (simply use `tabPanel` and not `tabPanel2`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(ggplot2)

tabPanel2 <- function(title, ..., value = title, icon = NULL, sidebarWidth = 4){
  tabPanel(
    title = title, 
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = sidebarWidth,
        class = "sidebar"
      ),
      column(
        width = 12 - sidebarWidth,
        ...
      )
    )
  )
}

sidebar <- function(...){
  div(
    style = "display: none;",
    tags$form(
      class = "well",
      id = "sidebar",
      ...
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  
  div( #~~ Main panel ~~#
    navbarPage(
      "Old Faithful Geyser Data",
      tabPanel2(
        "Plot",
        plotOutput("ggplot")
      ),
      tabPanel2(
        "Summary",
        verbatimTextOutput("summary")
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Table",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 4,
            wellPanel(
              tags$fieldset(
                tags$legend(h3("About")),
                p("This app is cool")
              )
            )
          ),
          column(
            width = 8,
            tableOutput("table")
          )
        )
      ),
      id = "navbar"
    )    
  ),
  
  sidebar( #~~ Sidebar ~~#
    sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)    
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output[["ggplot"]] <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
  
  output[["summary"]] <- renderPrint({
    list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10)
  })
  
  output[["table"]] <- renderTable({
    iris[1:10,]
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["navbar"]], {
    selector <- 
      sprintf("$('div.tab-pane[data-value=\"%s\"] div.sidebar')", input[["navbar"]])
    append <- "selector.append($('#sidebar'));"
    js <- sprintf("var selector=%s; if(selector.length){%s;}", selector, append)
    runjs(js)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't really like the appearance, I would prefer the title in the top left corner with the sidebar below and the tabs at the right, like in the example in my post. I guess it is possible to modify the layout you propose with CSS but I'm not comfortable enough with it to do so.

Comment: Yes it is better, but the `sliderInput` is under the plot in the first tab, whereas I would like it to be on the left (like in the two other tabs)

Comment: @bretauv See my second edit. This way resorts to JavaScript.

Comment: That's quite good, I guess I'll have to learn more about css to customize the position of the sidebar relative to the navbar for example. I have one last question though: suppose that I don't want to display this sidebar in the third tab (to put an "About" section for example), how can I do that?